# Как вернуть "200 OK" на запрос?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, http

Работаю с интеркассой. Считываю инфу о платеже:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#--*--coding: utf-8--*--

import cgi
import MySQLdb
from dbconfig import read_param
#from httplib import HTTPResponse
#import StringIO
"""
class FakeHttplibSocket(object):
    def __init__(self, response_string):
        self._buffer = StringIO.StringIO(response_string)

    def makefile(self, _mode, _other):
        return self._buffer

resp = "200 OK"
sock = FakeHttplibSocket(resp)
HTTPResponse(sock)
"""

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

id_kassa = form.getfirst('ik_co_id', '')   #ID кассы
pay_stat = form.getfirst('ik_inv_st', '')  #статус оплаты
sum_plat = form.getfirst('ik_co_rfn', '') #сумма зачисления на счёт кассы
dat_plat = form.getfirst('ik_inv_prc', '') #Дата платежа
user = form.getfirst('ik_x_user', '')       #Плательщик
sign = form.getfirst('ik_sign', '')           #Цифровая подпись в md5


try:
    id_kassa=str(id_kassa)
    pay_stat=str(pay_stat)
    sum_plat = int(sum_plat)
    dat_plat = str(dat_plat)
    user = str(user)
    sign = str(sign)
except ValueError:
    print "Ошибочные данные"

if id_kassa == "75yuyugiiug1jjdbe3ih8b4568":
    if pay_stat=="success":
        db_config = read_param()
        db = MySQLdb.connect(**db_config)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rub_in_out(login, sum_inc_dec, date_time) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", (user, sum_plat, dat_plat))
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

После этого, чтобы они мне повторно не слали этот запрос и платеж не задваивался, затраивался и т.д. (до 10 запросов повторных насчитал) мне 
нужно в ответ отправить им "200 OK".

В документации сказано:

> Внимание! Данное уведомление отправляется на сервер кассы по ссылке
>   страницы взаимодействия (Interaction URL) до тех пор, пока SCI, по
>   данному запросу, не получит от сервера кассы HTTP-код состояния,
>   которое указанно в настройках кассы (по умолчанию - "200 OK"). Так же,
>   см. настройки кассы "Текст подтверждения успешного получения
>   уведомления о статусе платежа".

Я не пойму, как мне им отправить "200 OK" ? Мне что нужно свой минивебсервер организовать, чтоб им это отправить?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114224/how-to-properly-send-http-response-with-python-using-socket-library-only

Comment: а возможно ли не биндить host и port? при использовании socket. а то я у хостера запускаю скрипт? Просто 
conn, addr = s.accept()
conn.send("200 OK")

Comment: нет 100% уверенности что там у хостера, пробуйте..

Comment: Если это у вас CGI скрипт, то ничего не нужно делать. [`200 ОК` по умолчанию возвращается.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-6.3.3)

Comment: @jfs, cgi. Но не возвращается. Так как callback запросы продолжают идти.

Comment: Что значит не возвращается? Какой код виден?

Comment: @jfs, Они шлют мне get запрос на мой скрипт с параметрами платежа. как я увижу что им отсылается? но судя по тому что запросы продолжают сыпаться, то ничего им в ответ не шлётся

Comment: Как увидеть? Тестировать со своим клиентом, логи сервера или просто трафик смотреть. Если запрос завершился, то код установлен (иначе это не http)

Comment: боже.... print("ok") и в настройках кассы поставить текст ответа "ok"

Comment: @eri, спасибо) вроде помогло. хотя точно не уверен. но по крайней мере новый что выбрал платёж. пришел только один раз. а старые так и прут...

Comment: твои ответы вроде в кассе можно посмотреть в админке

Comment: а что никто подпись не проверяет в скриптах оплаты? который раз вижу...

Comment: @eri, это же тестовые оплаты. в реальной естественно проверяю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы кассы ни чего кроме `print("ok")` не требуется в скрипте, а в настройках кассы при этом надо поставить текст ответа "ok".

Если смотреть глубже.

Ответ `200 ОК` возвращается скриптом cgi по умолчанию. Чтоб указать другой статус нужно в самом начале выводить заголовки ответа:

```
print("Status: 200 OK")     # Статус всегда самой первой строкой
print("Content-Type: text") # можно указать тип содержимого
print()                     # пустая строка для отделения заголовков от тела
```

Сервер http добавит недостающие заголовки, если их не указать явно.

Дальше выводится тело ответа. 
`print("ok")` поместит `ok\n` в ответ. В настройках кассы нужно указать такой же ответ для проверки доставки.

Вместо `ok` может быть что-то вроде `wn54wrthwtr45w`. Это немного увеличит безопасность.

Comment: стоит отметить, что это не имеет отношения к заголовку вопроса (не нужно в cgi скрипт добавлять `print("ok")`, чтобы получить HTTP статус 200.

Comment: @jfs на ваше замечание поясню в ответе вечером. Для меня казалось очевидным что ок в принте это тело ответа а преписка к статусу